# Error 504 bad gateway on Back Office of Prestashop store

Tags: nginx, prestashop-1.7, http-status-code-504

I have a problem with my Prestashop Store where sometimes I can get into Front Office without problems, but other times I get an error 504 and worse I cannot get into Back Office because get this error 504.

This is happening for four or five days and I don't know the root of the problem. I checked server logs but it only shows Negotiation error and idle timeout (120s) error. I cannot change the php.ini or nginx conf files because the hosting I have does not allow it (they say I need to change to VPS server to have root access and what I am using which is web cloud does not grant me access). I really need some guidance because I really don't want to lose possible customers.

Answer (score 0):

Just **increase timeout** of `fastcgi` directive.

On NGINX:

```
server{
  # ...
  fastcgi_read_timeout 60s;
  fastcgi_send_timeout 60s;
  # ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Based on these, the server you are using seems to be very weak.

The best solution is to switch to a server that supports PrestaShop (a dedicated PrestaShop package) and does not necessarily need a VPS.

Check this:
https://digital.com/best-web-hosting/prestashop/